# What's an accurate and affordable indoor positioning system

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, gps, arduino

**TL;DR version**

I'd like hardware capable of doing these things

1. Triangulate positions of nodes
2. Be accurate down to 1-6 inches
3. Able to see through fairly thin objects, like people/trees
4. Fairly inexpensive (Less than $50 per)

---

So, I'm wanting an [Indoor Positioning System (IPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system#Grid_concepts) to play around with.

What I want to try, isn't actually indoors, but I've been looking for affordable ways to do it indoor or outdoor.

I would like a way for several of my friends (I'll get the friends later) to be able to stand in a field, that has nodes at three corners of this field (in order to triangular positions of any other nodes).  So, let's call these three nodes at the corners of this triangular field, master nodes.

Each "friend" will be given a minion node (minion node = NOT master node) and the master nodes will be able to tell where the minion nodes are.  I'd like the accuracy to be as exact as possible (between 1-6 inches?).  So, let's say, each minion node had a defined coordinate that it would go to, and a light on it would turn green, and stayed red whenever they weren't in their position.  So basically they would run around to find a pre-defined position, at which point their minion node turns green.

Ok, so I know that there's ultra wide band technology that can do this, but it's pretty expensive....Like good ones tend to be over $100 per.  I know there's some zigbee stuff that can do it too, but maybe it's not so accurate.  Also, I know GPS could match this, but I want relative positions to the master nodes...Any other ideas, or reasons the ideas stated would actually work?

Any advice is welcome...maybe something that plugs into a Raspberry Pi or Arduino?  Thanks,